# Create Line joining common points

Tags: python, algorithm

I have list of coordinates and I want to create a chain (Line) from such points, e.g
input

```
[
  [
    ((1, 1), (2, 3)), ((1, 1), (3, 4))
  ],
  [
    ((2, 3), (6, 6)), ((3, 4), (7, 8))
  ],
  [
    ((7, 8), (9, 9)), ((6, 6), (9, 10)), ((6, 6), (7, 9))
  ],
  [
    ((11, 11), (12, 13))
  ]
]
```

and I want to create a chain *where we have common points* e.g in above input we have `(2, 3), (3, 4), (6, 6), (7, 8)` are common points.

Output: I want to gather all such common coordinates points and take a product out of them to create multiple candidate lines e.g

```
# expected outputs from above input
out1 = [((1, 1), (2, 3))] X [((2, 3), (6, 6))] X [((6, 6), (9, 10)), ((6, 6), (7, 9))]
out2 = [((1, 1), (3, 4))] X [((3, 4), (7, 8))] X [((7, 8), (9, 9))]

# will take product for combinations, which results in-
# for out1
= [((1, 1), (2, 3)), ((2, 3), (6, 6)), ((6, 6), (9, 10))]
= [((1, 1), (2, 3)), ((2, 3), (6, 6)), ((6, 6), (7, 9))]
```

Any pointer, pseudo code appreciated!

---

My attempt #1
**Works for first 2 list items :( Not sure how to extend it on complete list**

```
def pairs(ps):
    for i in range(1, len(ps)):
        yield (ps[i - 1], ps[i])

ls = [
    [((1, 1), (2, 3)), ((1, 1), (3, 4))],
    [((2, 3), (6, 6)), ((3, 4), (7, 8))],
    [((7, 8), (9, 9)), ((6, 6), (9, 10)), ((6, 6), (7, 9))],
    [((11, 11), (12, 13))],
]

master_list = []
for l in pairs(ls[:2]): # take fist 2 sub-list
    for k, v in groupby(sorted(l[0], key=lambda t: t[1]), key=lambda t: t[1]):
        new_ls = []
        t = [p for p in l[1] if p[0] == k]
        if t:
            new_ls.append(list(v))
            new_ls.append(t)
        master_list.append(new_ls)

gls = []
for m in master_list:
    for l in list(product(*m)):
        gl = nx.Graph() 
        print("Candidate Line: ", l)
        gl.add_edges_from(l)
        gls.append(gl)

nx.draw_networkx(gls[0])
```

output

```
Candidate Line:  (((1, 1), (2, 3)), ((2, 3), (6, 6)))
Candidate Line:  (((1, 1), (3, 4)), ((3, 4), (7, 8)))
```

Comment: for a pointer, forget about more than 2 lists. Just focus on the first two lists for now. Ask yourself "what are all the possible routes i can take" between two levels. Can you code that up ?

Comment: @sagarr what about common points (6, 6) and (7, 8)?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi `(7, 8)` already matched, see `out2`. `(6, 6)` is not common as there is no entry in next row (row 4) which starts with point `(6, 6)`

Comment: @sagarr still i don't get how do you chose common points

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi If I have point `(a, b)` x `(b, c)` then I can create a line `[a,b,c]` here `b` is common, same applies to my problem.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh added my attempt, it works for first 2 sub-list, need pointer to extend for complete input

Comment: What happens if you add `[(1, 2), (2, 3)]` to the example? Do you get four chains?

Comment: @fafl u mean for `out1`, yes will get 4. `ls =  [[((1, 1), (2, 3)), ((1, 2), (2, 3))], [((2, 3), (6, 6))], [((6, 6), (9, 10)), ((6, 6), (7, 9))]];list(product(*ls))`

Comment: What about circular structures, e.g. adding `((6, 6), (1, 1))`?

Answer (score 0):

Each element of `[E_0, ... E_n]` is a list of edges. You want to connect, if possible, an edge `u, v` from a list `E_k` to an edge `v, w` from the following list `E_{k+1}`. You can store, for each list `E_k`, the *from* vertices in a list `F_k` and the *to* vertices in an list `T_k`. If a vertice is in `T_k` and in `F_{k+1}`, then is is a common point as you defined it:

```
Es = [
    [((1, 1), (2, 3)), ((1, 1), (3, 4))],
    [((2, 3), (6, 6)), ((3, 4), (7, 8))],
    [((7, 8), (9, 9)), ((6, 6), (9, 10)), ((6, 6), (7, 9))],
    [((11, 11), (12, 13))],
]

Fs = [set(e[0] for e in E) for E in Es]
Ts = [set(e[1] for e in E) for E in Es]

commons = set(t for v, u in zip(Ts, Fs[1:]) for t in v & u)
# set([(3, 4), (2, 3), (7, 8), (6, 6)])
```